# Searching for base CMS

Tags: php, mysql, content-management-system

I'm searching for a PHP/MySQL based CMS with some basics like Register/Login.
It shouldn't be that complex like TYPO3.
Drupal and Joomla I don't want.

Comment: Based on the limited info you've provided, a google search for 'PHP CMS' would give you the answer. If you could elaborate on things like WHY you don't want Drupal and Joomla, as well as what other features you are looking for other than just 'login' folks can probably help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a list of notable Content Management Systems:

- [Wikipedia: List of content management systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Content_Management_Systems)

We could pick one for you, but most probably it would be a better idea if you check their features from that list in order to be in a position to make a better informed decision.

Comment: And: http://php.opensourcecms.com/

where you can also log in to demos at this site.

Answer (score 2):

Two that have been very good to me:

- [Symphony CMS](http://symphony-cms.com/) (not Symfony -- that's different) Symphony has a great community behind it, which is super uesful
- [Frog CMS](http://www.madebyfrog.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try either of [CMS Made Simple](http://www.cmsmadesimple.org/) or [One Page CMS](http://tero.co.uk/scripts/onepagecms.php)

Answer (score 0):

Another micro CMS: [snewscms.com](http://snewscms.com)